# How to check and release the memory occupied by DolphinDB stream engine?

Tags: memory, dolphindb

I have already unsubscribed a table in DolphinDB, but when I executed the function `getStreamEngineStat().AsofJoinEngine`, there was still memory occupied by the engine.

Does the function return the real-time memory information on the stream engine? How can I check the current memory status and release the memory?

Answer (score 0):

`getStreamEngineStat().AsofJoinEngine` does return the real-time memory information.

Undefining the subscription is not equivalent to dropping the engine. In your case, if you want to release the memory occupied by the engine, you need first use `dropStreamEngine` and set the variable returned by `createEngine` to be NULL.

Specific examples are as follows:

Suppose you define the engine as follows:

```
ajEngine=createAsofJoinEngine(name="aj1", leftTable=trades, rightTable=quotes, outputTable=prevailingQuotes, metrics=<[price, bid, ask, abs(price-(bid+ask)/2)]>, matchingColumn=`sym, timeColumn=`time, useSystemTime=false, delayedTime=1)
```

After undefining the subscription, you can correctly release memory by the following code:

```
dropStreamEngine("aj1")  // 1.release the specified engine
ajEngine = NULL          // 2. Release the engine handler from memory
```

If you find that the memory of the asofjoin engine is too large in the subscription, you can also specify the parameter garbageSize to clean up historical data that is no longer needed. The size of garbageSize needs to be set case by case, roughly according to how many records each key will have per hour.

The principle is: First, garbageSize is set for the key, that is, the data within each key group will be cleaned up. If garbageSize is too small, frequent cleaning of historical data will bring unnecessary overhead; if garbageSize is too large, it may not reach the threshold of garbageSize and cannot trigger cleaning, resulting in a leftover of unwanted historical data.

Therefore, it is recommended to clean up once per hour and set the garbageSize with a rough estimate.